# Android/OkHttp3, issues with basic authentication method

Tags: android, authentication, get, okhttp

I found it difficult to write a GET login request with `Okhttp3`, I state that I have never used it and work on Android for very little, being that even if I'm wrong I always get a confirmation code 200, how can I manage the login wrong?

**The Json:**

```
{
    "0": {
        "Stato Information": {
            "Stato": "Error",
            "Info": "Username/password Errati o Utente inesistente o Utente Disabilitato"
        }
    },
    "username_utente": "qwdadwa",
    "password_utente": "qdwe32"
}
```

**ActivityMain.java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText etUsername;
    private EditText etPassword;
    private Button btnLogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etUsername = findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                 String inputUsername = etUsername.getText().toString().trim();
                 String inputPassword = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                String url = "http://mytestendpointandblablabla&username_utente=" + inputUsername + "&password_utente=" + inputPassword + "&autologin=No";


                Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
                client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                            if (response.code() == 200) {
                                Intent intent = LoggedActivity.getLoggedActivityInstance(MainActivity.this);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else if(response.code() == 412) {
                                makeText(MainActivity.this, "Missing Data", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }}
```

Comment: The HTTP 200 OK success status response code indicates that the request has succeeded. It just tells you that communication with your api is working properly. The works needs to be done from Api side to check whether credentials are proper or not.

Comment: check here response.code().getSucess().equals("1") it needs to be done at server side

Comment: @ShivamOberoi .getSuccess() dont compile

Comment: you have to get that from server when response is successful

Comment: I cant work in the server side of the app, this is like a test to me, i have only to handle the android side

Comment: Your response is correct. I found that your Json info said **Incorrect username or password or non-existent user or disabled user**. Means all is ok except your username and password